# How to access java map object in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have following loop in my jsp page:

```
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${ toLvvt }" step="1">
      <c:set var="mapKey">${to.id}-${record.rId}-${record.opjakso}</c:set>
        <c:if test="${MyMap[mapKey].v1s eq true}">
           ...do something...
        </c:if>>
```

problem here is that I want to use `var i` fetching map object value (above `v1s`) like this: `v${i}s` but this is wrong.

I have map `Map<string, Object>`. Object has boolean properties v1s, v1k, v2s, v2k...

Comment: is `v1s` a property of the value in the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create it the same way as you created `mapKey`.

E.g.

```html
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${toLvvt}" step="1">
  <c:set var="mapKey" value="${to.id}-${record.rId}-${record.opjakso}" />
  <c:set var="property" value="v${i}s" />
  <c:if test="${MyMap[mapKey][property]}">
    ..
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

*(note that I simplified the one and other)*

Comment: Dude, thanks A LOT! This solved my problem. I was so close but never figured out that notation you provided...

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** ok after your modification I understand the question better, but I think what you are trying to do is not possible: you should probably try to implement a `List getVs()` on your map values that returns the list of `v{i}s` and then use it with `value.vs[i]` in your jsp.

For the record, my first answer was:

`<c:forEach>` is first intended to iterate over collections, you should thus try something like this:

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${MyMap}">
    <c:if test="${entry.value.v1s}">
        ...do something...
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

You may want to use a `LinkedHashMap` or a `TreeMap` if you want the output to be sorted somehow. You may also want to have a look at the [Display tag](http://www.displaytag.org/) library.

Comment: This wont solve my problem. That outer forEach loop is used to loop through changing set of years and I need direct access to my object in the map to check is it true or false/year

Answer (score -1):

Use Map key and value to fetch the map data on JSP page. It is easier way to iterate a map.

Example

```
<c:forEach items="${toLvvt}" var="toMap">
    <c:set var="mapKey" value="${toMap.key}" />
    <c:set var="mapValue" value="${toMap.value}" />
    <c:if test="${mapValue}">
    ..
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

.